# In a ring $a*a=0$ then $a+a=0$

Tags: ring-theory

I am stuck in a question for Algebraic Structures:

I need to prove: If given any ring $R$, for any $a$ in $R$ $a\cdot a=0$ then $a+a=0$.

(of course $+$, $*$ and $0$ regarding $R$)

I didn't find any question regarding this question.

Comment: Are you assuming that _every_ element of the ring squares to zero, or just _some_ element squares to zero?  The way your question is written, it isn't quite clear which you mean...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that the ring has a unit and that all elements of the ring square to 0.

In particular $1=1^2=0$ so the unit and zero must coincide. Thus for all $a\in R$ $$0=(a+1)^2=a^2+a+a+1=a+a,$$ proving that $a+a=0$ as desired.

---

Here is a counterexample if the ring is non-unital. Consider the matrix ring
$$
R=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&n\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\colon n\in\mathbb Z\right\},
$$
with usual matrix multiplication and addition as the ring operations. Then this ring has no unit, every element squares to zero, yet adding a non-zero element to itself results in a non-zero element of the ring.

Comment: As soon as the unit and $0$ coincide, the ring degenerates to the trivial one.

Comment: Oh right, of course. So I guess the assumption of a unit is overly restrictive here. (The question was unclear so I thought that was an implicit assumption being made.)

Comment: Hi, pre-Kidney thanks for the answer! The problem is that I was not given that the ring has a unit! but from the comments your assumption is correct, since this is incorrect if not a unit ring!

Comment: @Tomer The given "counterexample" has nothing to do with a unital assumption; it is a misunderstanding of the assumption of the problem.

Comment: @Tomer I don't believe anyone is claiming to know for sure what happens if the ring is not unital.

Comment: @Tomer you are very quick to jump to (wrong) conclusions.

Comment: I see that the commets were erased...

Why the example that in Z9 3*3=0 but still 3+3 does not equal 6 is not a good counter example? It is a ring (by the way it is a unity ring when 1 is the unit)?

Comment: Because the assumption is that **all** elements square to 0, not just a particular element squaring to 0. In this ring, $4*4\not=0$ so the assumption does not hold.

Comment: Note that your matrix ring counterexample is isomorphic to Jason's, since the multiplication of any two of those matrices is zero. In fact, any additive abelian group can be made into a non-unital ring by defining multiplication to be zero. It would be interesting to determine whether or not there are any other counterexamples. Note that the assumption gives $0 = (a+b)*(a+b) = a*a+a*b+b*a+b*b=a*b+b*a$, so multiplication must be *anti*-commutative.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I agree that this seems to be an interesting question, perhaps you should ask it in a separate post?

Comment: @pre-kidney I got an answer. I'll go ahead and post it as a supplement here.

Answer (score 4):

For a more non-trivial example of a non-unital ring which satisfies the hypothesis but not the conclusion, consider the set of matrices $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ s & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ t & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ u & -t & s & 0\end{pmatrix},$$ with $s, t, u \in \mathbb Z$. All such matrices square to zero, but adding such a matrix to itself does not give zero. This example contrasts from the ones given in the other answers by the fact that multiplying two of these matrices does not necessarily always give zero.

**Technical explanation:**

Let $R$ be the non-unital associative ring generated by elements $a, b$ modulo the relation that every element squares to zero. In fact, it is sufficient to enforce $a^2=0$, $b^2=0$, and $ab+ba=0$; that last relation is equivalent to $(a+b)^2=0$ in the presence of the first two relations. The resulting ring has a $\mathbb Z$-basis given by $a, b, ab$. We embed $R$ into a unital ring $R_1$ with basis $1, a, b, ab$, and consider the left regular representation of $R_1$ with respect to that basis. This gives the above faithful representation of $R \hookrightarrow R_1$.

**Even more technical overview of how one might attempt to simplify my example:**

One might ask if there is a lower-dimensional faithful representation for $R$, which would give smaller matrices above. I'm pretty sure the answer is no: If we extend scalars to a field (say, we denote $R^F := F \otimes_{\mathbb Z} R$ and $R_1^F := F \otimes_{\mathbb Z} R_1$, for $F$ a field), then the socle of this representation is $1$-dimensional, spanned by $ab$. The quotient by this socle yields a representation in which $ab$ is associated to the zero map. The radical of the regular representation is $3$-dimensional, spanned by $a$, $b$, and $ab$. This sub-representation also associates $ab$ to the zero map.

So as far as I can tell, the above $4$-dimensional representation is minimal dimension with respect to the constraint that $ab$ does not act by zero. More precisely, what the above argument establishes is that the only subquotient of the left regular representation of $R_1^F$ which doesn't kill $ab$ is the full left regular representation itself. It doesn't eliminate the possibility of a more clever way of taking a subquotient of a direct sum of a few copies of the left regular representation.

Another note: After extending scalars to a field as before, a representation of $R^F$ which doesn't kill $ab$ (i.e., one which doesn't render this counter-example trivial) is precisely the same thing as a faithful representation of $R^F$, precisely because of the socle condition mentioned above - every nontrivial ideal of $R^F$ contains $ab$. We have that $R_1^F$ is a local ring (non-units form an ideal) with Jacobson radical equal to $R^F$. So a faithful representation for $R^F$ automatically becomes a faithful representation for $R_1^F$, which is a unital embedding of $R_1^F$ into a matrix ring. An embedding into a $2 \times 2$ matrix ring would be an isomorphism, but matrix rings are not local rings. So that leaves the possibility of an embedding into a $3 \times 3$ matrix ring, a possibility which I don't think I've rigorously excluded.

Comment: It may be good to point out (before the technical explanation) that the reason this example is "more non-trivial" is because the product of distinct, non-zero matrices of this form can be non-zero, unlike in my example.

Also, setting $u=0$ gives a subring with the same properties, does it not? (This is in regards to the question of minimality of the representation.)

Comment: @pre-kidney By "minimality", I meant minimal dimension. The matrix given is just the matrix corresponding to the action of $s(a)+t(b)+u(ab)$ on the left regular representation; since multiplying $a$ and $b$ gives $ab$, $u$ can't really be eliminated. I'll add the point about multiplication being nonzero, and clarify my (still hand-wavy) minimality claim.

Answer (score 3):

If the ring has a unit then follow pre-kidney's answer. If not, the conclusion no longer follows. Take for instance $\mathbb Z$ with regular addition and a new multiplication defined by $x*y:=0$ for $x,y\in\mathbb Z$. (It is trivial to check that the ring axioms hold.) Clearly $x*x=0$ for all $x$ but $x+x\neq0$ unless $x=0$.