# In a ring $a \cdot a=a$ then $a+a=0$

Tags: ring-theory

I am stuck in a question for Algebraic Structures:

I need to prove the following:

> Let $R$ be a ring. If $a^2=a$ for any $a\in R$, then $a+a=0$ for any $a\in R$.

(of course $+$, $\cdot$ and $0$ regarding $R$)

P.S.
This is similar to a [different question I asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192674/in-a-ring-aa-0-then-aa-0) (if $a \cdot a = 0$ then $a + a = 0$) but I wasn't able to apply the ideas from there. In that question we assumed that $R$ is a unity ring.

Comment: Not true in the integers modulo $4$. $1*1=1$, but $1+1=2$

Comment: Hey it is also true for Modulo 4 since the assumption is that for every a a*a=1

Comment: I think what is meant is:  if $R$ is a ring such that $a^2=a$ for all $a$, then $a+a=0$ for all $a\in A$. Is this true?

Comment: Hey @DietrichBurde as mentioned in the P.S. this is slightly different (if this is not enough of a change I will gladly erase the question :-) )

Comment: The statement is unclear to me. Who is $a$ in $a+a=0$ ? Is it all those that satisfy $a*a=a$ ? Is it, if for any $a$ one has $a*a=a$ then for any $a$ one had $a+a=0$ ?

Comment: Hi @JamesWell yes it is for every a in R

Comment: @DietrichBurde instead of a*a=0 it is a^2=a

Comment: Oh, I am sorry! Yes, it is different (but with almost the same proof).

Comment: Yeah its cool I understood it looks similar

Comment: For some reason I didnt get it, and was not able to use the proof over there

Comment: @DietrichBurde and whoever else voted to close, I would recommend you retract your close votes, so no one else makes the same mistake.

Comment: Given Aweygan's answer, I think the question would have been clearer this way : Prove that given a ring $R$ $\forall a \in R \quad (a*a=0 \implies a+a=0)$. This means the implication is true for any $a$ but the property $a*a=0$ need not be satisfied by every $a$ in order to conclude on a specified element ;)

Comment: @JamesWell The question is a little different, it's $a^2 = a$, all elements are idempotent, i suppose you could rephrase it as "Given a ring $R$, $\forall a \in R$ we have ($a^2=a, \, (a + a)^2 = a + a \implies a + a = 0$)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a\in R$ be given.  Then $$a+a=(a+a)^2=a\cdot a+a\cdot a+a\cdot a+a\cdot a=a+a+a+a.$$
Adding $-(a+a)$ to both sides yields the result.